# Multiple Callback Functions with the Node Twitter Library

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, twitter, callback

I'm trying to make requests to Twitter with [Twitter for Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) and store responses in an array for handling later. I'm pushing returned tweets to an array with each `push()` happening in a callback, which seems to be working fine. **My problem is that I'm having trouble accessing the full array with all pushed tweets.**

The cause, of course, is that any attempt to work with that array is getting called before the results from the Twitter API have arrived, so I'm getting an empty array.

How can I (and should I) get my function working with the full array into another callback? I'm asking this from the perspective of someone still trying to get a firm grasp on asynchronous programming - especially multiple callbacks or functions that have to run asynchronously.

**Again, current result is `tweetHold = []`, and I'd like `tweetHold` to contain all matched tweets for all users in the `searchArray`.**

```
let searchArray = {
  users: ['ByBuddha', 'thetweetofgod']
}

let tweetHold = [];  

let T = new Twitter(config);

for (user of searchArray.users) {

  let params = {
    q: 'from:'+ user,
    count: 1,
    tweet_mode: 'extended',
    result_type: 'recent',
    lang: 'en'
  }

  T.get('search/tweets', params, returnedTweets);

}

function returnedTweets(err, tweets, response) {
  tweetHold.push(tweets);
}

// obviously, doesn't work as the array is logged to console before T.get() is done
console.log(tweetHold);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T.get` accepts a callback function that gets called once the asynchronous operation is done. But since you want to get *multiple* responses, and not just one, using just the callbacks by themselves would be a bit messy. For example, inside `returnedTweets`, you could increment a persistent counter variable, and call the next function once `counter === searchArray.users.length`, but it would be more elegant to use Promises instead.

Map each `T.get` call to a `Promise` that resolves with the `tweets` variable you're interested in, and then call `Promise.all` on an array of those Promises. `Promise.all` takes an array of `Promises` and returns a `Promise` that resolves once every Promise in the passed array has resolved.

Note that it looks like you're currently ignoring the `err` that might come back from `T.get` - that's probably not a good idea, it would be better to be able to check when errors occur, and then handle the error somehow (otherwise, the `tweetHold` array may sometimes contain broken data). Luckily, if you use Promises, implementing this is easy - just `reject` if there's an `err`, and `catch` after the `Promise.all`:

```
const T = new Twitter(config);
const searchObject = {
  users: ['ByBuddha', 'thetweetofgod']
};

const searchPromises = searchArray.users.map((user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
      q: 'from:'+ user,
      count: 1,
      tweet_mode: 'extended',
      result_type: 'recent',
      lang: 'en'
    };
    T.get('search/tweets', params, (err, tweets) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(tweets);
    });
  });
});

Promise.all(searchPromises)
  .then((tweetHold) => {
    // tweetHold will be an array containing the `tweets` variable for each user searched
    console.log(tweetHold);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // there was an error, best to handle it somehow
    // the `.then` above will not be entered
  });
```